# load original values of entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I recently started working with C# & EF and entities and i need a help to understand something when loading object.I have an object which have a lot of properties and half of the them are decimal values.I use windows forms so every time am loading a form i declare my context and then load an object from context like this

```
myEntities context= new myEntities();
Autocase acase=context.Autocase.Where(a => a.ID == 175555).FirstOrDefault();
```

then user is able to change the properties values of acase object.
So when acase was loaded the acase.TotalPrice was 0.
after user input acase.TotalPrice is 100.
Now my program needs to check if TotalPrice has been changed and act accordingly.
what i did was to create a new object the same way  i created the first and then compare TotalPrice.

```
Autocase bcase=context.Autocase.Where(a => a.ID == 175555).FirstOrDefault();
```

when i tried to compare the TotalPrice

```
if(acase.TotalPrice!=bcase.TotalPrice){some code here}
```

i noticed that bcase had exactly the same values as acase so TotalPrice will always be the same.Looks like bcase is loading reference to acase.(context has not been saved since acase has been changed).Then i tried something else.

```
decimal oldTotalPrice=context.Autocase.Where(a => a.ID == 175555).Select(a=>a.TotalPrice).SingleOrDefault();
```

and it got the old TotalPrice !!!!!
So as i understand trying to reload an object from context that has been already loaded will point to the first loaded object, while trying to load single values of an object that has been already loaded and modified will load the original values. Have i understand this correct? Is that the normal behavior ? or there is something i should be aware and i am not.
I have found a way to get the object original values by creating another context in using block and get the original objects values fine.Just wanted to know if this behavior is correct so i am aware of it or am i missing something.
Thanks in advance to who ever takes time to explain.

Comment: Yes, that’s normal. The objects are cached and tracked but selecting just some properties of them might not be. You can check if things have changed for a specific object through EF change tracking system, but it might not be that nice or performant if you need to do a lot of it

Comment: thank you very much for clarification. If has changed i need to do a lot so will stick with the workaround i found creating a new context in using block and get the original values of entire object. Thanks again for your time.